# Smart pointers in C++ APIs?

Tags: c++, api, c++11, smart-pointers

It is fairly often suggested not to use raw pointers in modern C++, except for a few rare cases. What is the common practice of using smart pointers in C++ library APIs?

The following use cases come up to my mind:

1. A function which returns a new object.
2. A function which returns a new object, but it has also created another reference to this object.
3. A function which only uses an object it receives as an argument.
4. A function which takes over the ownership of an object.
5. A function which will store a reference to an object which it has received as an argument, but there might be other references to the very same object (from the callers side).

Comment: "5. A function [storing] a reference [...,] not care about potential other references." - this is vague.  It doesn't care because it knows the object's lifetime will outlive its use?  If so, it can take the address of a reference or accept a raw pointer.  If it doesn't know that then it ultimately needs a weak pointer.

Comment: What I meant was that either the object is immutable (i.e. sharing to reduce memory usage), or it is simply no problem, if the object is mutated through other aliases.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: 5 now clearly suggests a `std::shared_ptr<>` as per Matthieu's answer, but the rewrite makes your "`const std::shared_ptr<Foo>&` / to prevent adjusting the reference count when the function is called and when it returns" bad advice, so I'm not sure if the question describes what you originally intended (but modifying it again would be unfair to Matthieu - if you have another distinct scenario of interest, add it at 6).

Comment: Why is const-ref to shared pointer bad advice? With plain shared_ptr, reference count adjusted at: 1) function call; 2) when the function actually copies the reference for its own use; 3) function returns. With const-ref reference count is adjusted at 2) only.

Comment: See [GotW #91](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) for an explanation (especially points e) and f))....

Comment: @TonyD: this does not really argue why const-ref to shared pointer is bad advice. It says to prefer making the distinction between shared_ptr<widget> and const shared_ptr<widget>& based on API clarity, and it says that if we copy any way, then it is not much overhead to copy twice than to copy once.

Comment: It also explains why your justification concerning extra increments and decrements of the reference count is unfounded given `std::move`.

Comment: @TonyD: Well, then in the function you have to care about using the other shared pointer after the move... But yes, in that case there are no performance implications.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, a library API design goes far beyond the rule of the language itself: suddenly you have to care about implementations details such as the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

Contrary to C, where common implementations can easily interact together, C++ implementations have very different ABIs (Microsoft ABI for VC++ is completely incompatible with the Itanium ABI used by gcc and Clang), and C++ Standard Library implementations are also incompatible with each others, so that a library compiled with libstdc++ (bundled with gcc) cannot be used by a program using another major version of libstdc++ or another implementation such as libc++ (bundled with Clang) if `std::` classes appear in the interface.

Therefore, it really depends on whether you intend your library to be delivered as a binary or assume the user will be in a position to compile the library with its own compiler and Standard Library implementation of choice. Only in the latter case should you expose a C++ interface, for binary distributions sticking to C is better (and it's also easier to integrate with other languages).

---

With that out of the way, let's assume you decided to use a C++ API:

> 1) A function which returns a new object.

If the object can be returned by value, do so; if it is polymorphic, use `std::unique_ptr<Object>`.

> 2) A function which returns a new object, but it has also created another reference to this object.

*Rare Case*. I suppose that you mean it has kept a reference, somehow. In this case you have shared ownership so the obvious choice is `std::shared_ptr<Object>`.

> 3) A function which only uses an object it receives as an argument.

Much more complex than it first seems, even supposing no reference to the object is kept.

- in general, pass by reference (`const` or not)
- unless you intend to operate on a copy of the object, in which case pass by value to benefit from a potential move

> 4) A function which takes over the ownership of an object.

Simple ownership: `std::unique_ptr<Object>`.

> 5) A function which will store a reference to an object which it has received as an argument, but there might be other references to the very same object (from the callers side).

Shared ownership: `std::shared_ptr<Object>`

Comment: Note that a libraries C binary API can be wrapped in a header-only C++ API that gets compiled by the client.

Comment: @Yakk: which starts getting interesting when, like for Clang, you have a core C++ implementation exposing a C API (for binary stability) and decide to wrap it in a header-only C++ API (for ease of use) :)

Answer (score 7):

1. Unique pointers may do the job in the general case.

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<Foo> func();
   ```

   So that you can assign them directly to `auto` variables at the callers site, and not worry about memory management.

   ```
   auto u = func();
   ```

   In case you need shared ownership, you can convert smart pointers on the callers site:

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<Foo> s{func()};
   ```

   However, in case the return type of the function is not polymorphic, *and* that type is fast to move, you may prefer *return by value*:

   ```
   Foo func();
   ```
2. Shared pointers.

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<Foo> func();
   ```
3. Simply use a reference or const reference to the object, with raw pointers or smart pointers "dereferenced" at the callers site.

   ```
   void func(Foo& obj);
   void func(const Foo& obj);
   ```

   In case the parameters are optional, you may use raw pointers, so that you can easily pass a `nullptr` to them.

   ```
   void func(Foo *obj);
   void func(const Foo *obj);
   ```
4. Unique pointers.

   ```
   void func(std::unique_ptr<Foo> obj);
   ```
5. Const reference to shared pointers.

   ```
   void func(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& obj);
   ```

   The const reference (to shared pointer) is simply an optimization to prevent adjusting the reference count when the function is called and when it returns.

Comment: 1. Return by value. 3. Depends on whether the function needs a local copy or not.

Comment: I agree - although #3 could also be plain raw pointers if a `nullptr` is a valid argument. Raw pointers as function arguments in modern C++ simply mean "can be null, but I won't accuire any ownership of what you give me."

Comment: @juanchopanza depends, e.g. on how expensive moving that object is, and if the return type is a base class pointer (think of factories).

Comment: @ArneMertz The cost of moving only matters if there is no RVO. But in general "return a unique_ptr" should not be the default action. It should be used only if necessary.

Comment: Unless for some reason you want to keep track of the state of the `shared_ptr` (i.e. its ref count), I can't see any reason for #5. You should just store a reference to the actual object.

Comment: "4. A function which takes over the ownership of an object. / `void func(std::unique_ptr<Foo> obj);` - it's noteworthy that this argument type isn't enough to guarantee exception safety for multi-argument function calls - some manner of `make_unique<>` is also needed as explained in [GOTW 102](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/)

Comment: @juanchopanza, ArneMertz:  I incorporated your suggestions. I don't think a library designer should rely on RVO, since the user of the library may write code to which RVO is not applicable.

Comment: @MiklósHomolya I am not sure how the user could achieve that. Do you have an example in mind? Anyway, I still think returning by value should be the default case.

Comment: "may write code to which RVO is not applicable" - *even then* a move operator makes many classes cheap and *doesn't force dynamic memory allocation*.

Comment: The user of the library doesn't write the library o_O, so it matters not what code they may write that cannot be RVOed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question but also an important one.

One school of thought missing from the answers is that you should not return raw *nor* smart pointers from your **API** if you can help it.

The raw pointer issue has been discussed.  But smart pointers can also be misused, especially in larger projects with complex internal APIs.

A workaround is creating an RAII/wrapper object that holds the ( never-exposed ) smart pointer.